# Django account and unique users per account concept

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out the best way to model and implement a Django project with the concept of accounts and unique users per account.

The built in auth and users model seemed good at first, but from my tests it has no concept of accounts, just groups (which I don't think gives me enough here).

I thought of using the existing auth User model and adding an account and account user model to join the two. This worked at first but didn't work with the django provided admin site as an account is not needed, failing the authenticate check.

What I require is:

- The concept of accounts
- Users that are linked to one or more accounts that they can only log into but not the Django admin site
- Admin users that can log into the Django admin site AND any account

I'm thinking at some point I will need to store the account model in the session for accessing any data related to the account, is that the preferred way for this?

Any suggestions and how to do this with Django best practice would be very helpful!

Comment: One note: admins should not be able to log into accounts; if they can, "the admin did it" becomes an excuse (and you could be criminally liable in some situations, but don't hold me to that). Please rethink this.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 "the admin did it" can always be an excuse. If you are worried about that, you need good auditing. Impersonating users is a common feature and can be integrated into that auditing.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "account", but maybe [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) can help you.